# How to add label above UIProgressView in UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar, uiprogressview

I have a UIToolbar in which I have placed a UIProgressView successfully. However, I have seen some apps contain a small label above the UIProgressView which tells the user what the program is doing where progress is being made -- e.g. to download a file. However it seems that this cannot be done in UI Builder. Any ideas on the best way to add the label ablve the UIProgressView in the toolbar? Here is what I am interested in:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|         Uploading File                         |
| ================--------------------  [CANCEL] |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom `UIView` that contains a `UILabel` and `UIProgressView` as subviews. You then insert the custom `UIView` into the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually also add text directly to a `UIProgressView` as a subview, ex:

```
UIProgressView *videoProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width - 80, 40)];

UILabel *processing = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, videoProgressView.frame.size.width, 25)];
processing.text = @"Processing Video...";
processing.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[videoProgressView addSubview:processing];

[self.view addSubview:videoProgressView];
```

Just make sure `UIProgressView`'s `clipsToBounds` property is set to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 5 implementation of [Lyndsey Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28181588/9297460) used in my project:

```swift
let view = UIApplication.topViewController()!.view!

let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
progressView.center = view.center
progressView.trackTintColor = .gray
progressView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: view.frame.size.height / 2, width: view.frame.size.width - 80, height: 40)
      
let progressViewLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -50, width: progressView.frame.size.width, height: 25))
progressViewLabel.text = "Migrating database:"
progressViewLabel.textAlignment = .center
      
progressView.addSubview(progressViewLabel)
      
view.addSubview(progressView)
```